# How to edit javascript response in 'save response to a file' in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am getting rest call response in **javascript** format.I could save whole response in a local file.but I have to save a part of response that is a javascript variable's value.

Please find my javascript response data:

In the below code I want to save the value of the **s0.responseTextJson** and need to parse the json string before saving into the file.

```
var s0=new Response();s0.api=null;s0.ckStatus=200;s0.ckStatusText="OK";
s0.responseText="{\"com.response-message\":{}}";
s0.responseTextJson="{\"com.response-message\":{}}";
s0.responseTextXml="<ns4:response-message></ns4:response-message>";
s0.responseType='JSON';
dwr.engine._remoteHandleCallback('0','0',s0);
```

[Please click here to see the screenshot of actual response in jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvQ2w.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns above JavaScript and configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `s0.responseTextJson`
   - Regular Expression: `s0.responseTextJson="(.+?)";`
   - Template: `$1$`
2. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   sample_variables=s0.responseTextJson
   ```

   See [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) User Manual entry to learn what's going on here.
3. Restart JMeter to pick the property up.
4. [Run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
5. Once your test is finished you will see the new column called `s0.responseTextJson` in your .jtl results file, it will hold the relevant value for each HTTP Request sampler

   [image: JMeter Response Variable]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dmitri.
I could solve it by using BeanShell PostProcessor.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue in above question just by adding a BeanShellPostProcessor with below script.

```
String originalResponse = new String(data);
String filteredResponse = 
originalResponse.substring(originalResponse.indexOf("s0.responseTextJson=\"")+21, originalResponse.indexOf("\";s0.responseTextXml=\"")).replace("\\\\","#temp#").replace("\\","").replace("#temp#","\\");
prev.setResponseData(filteredResponse.getBytes());
```

[Please click here to see my BeanShellPostProcessor in Jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOw9T.png)